# What is the fastest way to insert text into a <div> element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am writing a long series of numbers to my document, one at a time. document.write() handles this fine, but using innerHTML with a `<div>` element is sluggish, and rather quickly crashes my tab.  Is there some way to insert text into a `<div>` element that is as fast as document.write?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, based on Vlad idea that should be as fast as possible:

```
var arrData = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
    arrData.push(i);
var oDiv = document.getElementById("Output");
oDiv.innerHTML = arrData.join(", ");
```

Instead of appending to a string or to the `innerHTML` which are both slow, append to array then use `join` to get the string out of the array. The above example will throw 5000 numbers into the output div and it takes 2 milliseconds instead of 2.5 seconds when doing it with `oDiv.innerHTML += i + ", ";`

Live test case available here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/mKx35/

Answer (score 1):

Is displaying the results one at a time critical? You could write them into a string one at a time, and then flush it into the div with innerHTML.

Comment: It is.  I have tried your suggestion, but it appears to be just as slow (my tab still crashes, anyway).

Comment: What numbers of items are we talking about? Maybe you could try using a combined approach, i.e. adding a 100 elements to a string, flushing it, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`cloneNode` and `appendChild` are quite fast on modern browsers.

If the JS takes too long consider using a queue and timer events (e.g. `setInterval`) to "yield" control periodically and prevent "script timeout" errors.

Perhaps there is a better way to approach the situation -- how many divs and *why*?

Answer (score 0):

You could *try* node.textContent = "foo" but im not sure how much faster it will be, assuming it's not slower.